# Zinnia Templates for List and detail view

Tags: django, django-cms, zinnia

I am trying to integrate zinnia into a django application. I have to adept the zinnia templates into my theme. Now I am stuck, because it seems that zinnia is using the same template to build the blog entry list, and the blog entry detail page.

This is problematic because, the list has significant different html and css as the entry single view. How do I split the templates, so that I have one that is entirely for the list and one for the entry's detail (Single Post) ?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge this isn't easily done.  Here is a comment on a bug asking about this very issue:

[Template Documentation #383](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/issues/383#issuecomment-96582420)

For me I am going to modify zinnia/_entry_detail_base.html and put my list view template code in an {% if continue_reading %} and the detail template in the else branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently in the process of integrating the Zinnia engine into custom templates -- I'm working on a dynamically updating homepage that shows recent entries from multiple categories, custom pages for each of those categories, and then custom templates for the entries' detail views. I've found this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359992/use-zinnia-template-tags-in-blog-template?rq=1) and [this explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-blog-zinnia/hQRv01egorw/BAdRuq-YAN0J) to be extremely helpful.

*Keep in mind that the second link is a bit dated, and that `{% load zinnia_tags %}` is now `{% load zinnia %}`.

It's still a lot of trial and error to get things adapted properly to a custom template, but Zinnia really is amazingly customizable, and I think its default configuration tends to overshadow the fact that it works brilliantly as an underlying engine that can power just about any framework that you can sketch out on a notepad.

As the [documentation notes](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/how-to/customize_look_and_feel.html), it's also helpful to take a look at some custom themes built for Zinnia on GitHub, just to get a feel of how the template tags are implemented, and how the default templates can be overridden. Here's the repo for a [Bootstrap theme](https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/zinnia-theme-bootstrap), and here's one for a [Foundation theme](https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/zinnia-theme-foundation).

Comment: The linked documentation seems new to me. I have changed to aldryn-newsblog which is not that heavyweight and easily customizable. As I am using django-cms it is also more update friendly for my setup. As long as there is a lot of trial and error zinnia is broken/unusable to me, although I think it might be a great tool.

Comment: Hey -- I actually started on Aldryn Newsblog, too! I really think that starting with a simpler engine isn't a bad idea. I only moved to Zinnia when I learned NewsBlog well enough to see the limitations.

I'd always wanted a homepage that would dynamically change based on new entries and their categories, and I found that very confusing with NewsBlog (but, I had to move to regular django for Zinnia to finally click with me), and here's where I've gone since my answer (I think it's a good example of using Zinnia, but not looking like Zinnia's default config at all): www.fringeclass.net

Comment: It would be nice then, if you could share maybe some template knowledge, I might not change but at least I want to know options for later projects.

Comment: I actually ended up [answering my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012232/how-can-i-register-templatetag-in-zinnia-for-displaying-latest-entries-in-specif/38040789#38040789) in another thread, I made quite a bit of process in extending its defaults since my last comment here. Also: You can take a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sparkholiday/fringeclassdeploy) for the site, hopefully it provides some inspiration :)