# Use zinnia template tags in blog template

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I am using Zinnia to make backend for blog on my website. The frontend is read and I just want to plug in the backend to display blog list, archives, tags etc. Zinnia has `templatetags` to display these but I cannot find any documentation on how to use it.
If I have the frontend, how do I display blog list using templatetags?

Answer (score 1):

To use any of the Zinnia template tags, you need to load them first at the top of your template. This can be done by:

```
{% load zinnia %}
```

After this you can use any of the Zinnia template tag.

**Some Usage Example:**

- **get_recent_entries**

It will get the most recent entries and then display them. You can specify the `number` of items to be displayed and the `template_name` for the template to be used for displaying.

```
{% get_recent_entries 5 "my_template.html" %}
```

- **get_featured_entries**

It will display the featured entries. You can specify `number` and `template_name` as the arguments for the template_tag.

```
{% get_featured_entries 5 "my_template.html" %}
```

- **get_popular_entries**

It will display the popular entries. Here also, You can specify `number` and `template_name` as template_tag arguments.

```
{% get_popular_entries 5 "my_template.html" %}
```

**Documentation:**

For referring to the Zinnia documentation, check this link.

http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/develop/index.html